# Bad format in JSON response AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the follow code, it's call a web service in other PC server.
Data parameters are ok.

```
"{ ControlId: 'ZAsociated_26037', TaskId: 1495613, UserId: 166396,  TBodyId: ''}"
```

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",        
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ ControlId: '" + controlId + "', TaskId: " + taskid + ", UserId: " +
              userId + ",  TBodyId: '" + $(tbody).attr("id") + "'}",
        url: getWSPath() + "/GetZAsociatedResults", // CARGAR AQUI LA DIRECCION DEL WEBSERIVCE
        success: function (data) {         

            if (data != null && data.d != "[]") loadAsociatedTable(controlId, data.d);
           $("#loadingImg" + controlId).remove();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           $("#loadingImg" + controlId).remove();
           alert("Error al obtener los datos: " +thrownError + "\nCodigo de error: " +xhr.status);          
        }
    });
```

The error is, that when i have the data.d result of WS, JSON add adicionals "\" chars in string:

The begin of response:
**[{\"Nombre del Documento\":\"Indemnizacion/Factura. 22076 - Proveedor - Sin: 38653 Global: No\",\"Estado\":\"Pago finalizado\",**

I try to replace "\" to null string but it doesnt work

This AJAX when success call to loadAsociatedTable function and this do:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < $.parseJSON(data).length;i++){
```

and have an error in $.parseJSON(data).length because don't converter this string to object.

I checked in Chrome and the JSON is ok, without this bar "\", and recognize that like a object, the problem is in IE v.11 only.

Comment: What is the error message you're receiving from `$.parseJSON(data)`? And, is `data` there the 2nd parameter of `loadAsociatedTable()`? Are you trying to both `.replace()` and `$.parseJSON()`? Have you tried just `$.parseJSON(data.d)` within `success`?

Comment: The error of $.parseJSON(data).lenght is "Object does not support property or method 'parseJSON'", the JSON is bad contains additionals "\", and when I try to have the lenght of the object I have this error. And yes, the second parameter of  loadAsociatedTable is the response of this AJAX

Comment: The error relates to the `$` object itself not having a `parseJSON()` method. Are you using jQuery or a similar library for `$`? What version are you using? In jQuery, [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) was added with 1.4.1 and isn't available in lower versions.

Comment: The response of your last question is: yes, but I have a lot of "\" in some parameters of JSON, the latest lines are: \"Estado solicitud x liquidador\":null,\"Honorarios por tabla\":null,\"Gastos por tabla\":null,\"Ruta Documento\":\"\\\\\\\\172.18.33.3\\\\Stardoc\\\\ZambaVolumenes\\\\Desarrollo\\\\VolSiniestros\\\\VOLSIN011\\\\26037\\\\13\\\\4859528.pdf\",\"DoctypeId\":\"26037\",\"IdDoc\":4859528}]"

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Comment: What does the actual JSON response look like? Exactly as it's sent to your web browser, not what's displayed in the console or anything.

Comment: I get the answer of AJAX in response -> data.d. I can't debbug the WS because is in another PC, this is a server and I can't install VS. I show you the response that i get from AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you Post the complete JSON which will help me to analyze 
In meanwhile try this

Using Eval on data.d like eval("{"+data.d+"}");

or JSON.Parse(data.d)

try validate you json here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The data.d is "[{\"Nombre del Documento\":\"Indemnizacion/Factura. 22034576 - Proveedor - Sin: 3865233 Global: No\",\"Estado\":\"Pago finalizado\",\"ID Comprobante\":22540476,\"Nro de Siniestro\":38653,\"Sector\":\"Siniestros Ramas Varias\",\"Rama\":\"INTEGRAL COMERCIO\",\"Administración\":null,\"Ingresado por\":\"prettimaur\",\"Tipo Beneficiario\":\"Proveedor\",\"Beneficiario\":\"ESTUDIO SANTAMARINA SA\",\"Proveedor\":null,\"Nro Orden de Pago\":230934562,\"Fecha propuesta por Siniestros\":null,\"Fecha Comprobante\":\"\\/Date(1378782000000)\\/\"}]"

Comment: I checked in Chrome and the JSON is ok, without this bar "\", and recognize that like a object, the problem is in IE v.11 only.

Answer (score 0):

The server's JSON response is invalid. Some server programmer has misunderstood JSON double quote escaping and tried to apply it everywhere. Have the server return valid JSON. Most server environments have standard JSON libraries which will construct JSON which is not invalid. The correct JSON is of course just

```
[{"Nombre del Documento":"Indemnizacion/Factura. 22076 - Proveedor - Sin: 38653 Global: No","Estado":"Pago finalizado", ...
```

You can try to fix the JSON yourself, by replacing `\"` with `"`, which would just be

```
replace(/\\"/g, '"')
```

but the problem is that you will also destroy `\"` sequences representing double quote marks inside string values. That's quite a tricky problem to solve. So the best solution is to get the server to send down correct JSON to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the problem, I used JSON.parse() instead $.parseJSON(), maybe is JQuery version. AJAX response contains this additionals "\" but when I parse this object, JS convert it without problems.
Thanks for your help!